# Upload a file using POST API in Katalon

Tags: file, post, katalon-studio

I need to upload a 2MB .yml file as POST request body.I selected body type as file and uploaded the file.
When I give header as Content-Type : multipart/form-data I get the error message `Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found`
When I dont mention Content-type , error is `Content type '' not supported`

How to Post a file using Katalon?

Comment: Is this specific to Katalon? Do you get the same error messages when using other tools?

Comment: This is curl command working fine "curl -X POST "httpsXXXX" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "KEY: XXXX" -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=@Script.v.1.7.6.3.yml;type=""

Comment: I fixed it...I was selecting File instead of form-data. Silly mistake.. :P